# Post request by QWebEngineHttpRequest (PyQt5)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I have a question about making POST request in PyQt5.
Unfortunately official documentation for this framework for Python doesen't exist. I have to translate docs from C++ to Python.

I have a problem with handle it. To make POST request I have to create instance of class `QWebEngineHttpRequest` ([docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qwebenginehttprequest.html)), and then add POST data by `setPostData()`,  it looks to be easy, but that method requires a parameter in type `QByteArray` ([docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qbytearray.html)), and here is a problem because i don't know how to insert data into this.

Comment: in a post request a data is sent, what data are you going to send?

Comment: you are right, this is a data not parameter, I want to send just plain/text

Comment: a QByteArray in python are [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes), so you could use `b''` or QtCore.QByteArray(), without being clear which is the request you want to send, I could not help you anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know I'm late, but I hope it helps someone else with the same issue. Here's how I've done it:

```
def postRequest(self):
    self.url = QUrl()
    self.req = QWebEngineHttpRequest()

    self.url.setScheme("http")
    self.url.setHost("stackoverflow")
    self.url.setPath("/something/somethingelse")

    self.req.setUrl(self.url)
    self.req.setMethod(QWebEngineHttpRequest.Post)
    self.req.setHeader(QByteArray(b'Content-Type'),QByteArray(b'application/json'))

    params = {"something": value, "test": True, "number": 5}

    self.req.setPostData(bytes(json.dumps(params), 'utf-8')) 
    
    return self.req
```